# How to export bash variable from function execed in prompt to parent shell?

Tags: bash, function, export, prompt

Oh... Probably title is not really easy to interpret. So let's describe it a little bit:

In `.bashrc` file I set `PS1` to get custom prompt. In this prompt I need to have some additional info, which I get from other specific function. This function takes some time to exec so it is not cool to wait 1 sec after push enter in console. But I have idea to cached returned value from this specific function.

I need to check cache flag in every prompt print so I cant use variable, I must use function in printing prompt, because sourceing `.bashrc` is only one times, but if I pass function to `PS1` it will be execed every time.

```
prompt_fun(){

    export CACHE_YES=1
    export PROMPT_CACHE="Something"
    echo "$PROMPT_CACHE"    

        #in real case here will be checking if cache is turned on. 
        #If yes, we use cached value from exported variable in first time.
        #If no, we exec specific function and export values to env variables.
}

PS1="$(prompt_fun): "`
```

Of course, variable `CACHE_YES` and `PROMPT_CACHE` are not set in console, so I am unable to control caching be changing `CACHE_YES`. I know when cache should change so I can type in console to change `CACHE_YES=0` but my script don't rechange it to `CACHE_YES=1` after cache new values.

How to make that `export` in `prompt_fun` have global effect?

Comment: A child process cannot directly affect environment variables within its parent process. One possibility may be to go through the filesystem... your mysterious process that takes over a second could maybe write into the filesystem somewhere and your prompt_fun() could read it.

Comment: There is difference? If I use command to get info which I need to print in prompt then I use command to get info to write it to file and read it back? Or maybe you mean that cache flags send to files and read them from file? Probably this will work but I'm unsure about time of reading file each time I print prompt. Elegance solution should't make temporary files, because there will be also problem with work on multiply command lines with same temp cache file for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, you can't. Since `prompt_fun` is called in a command substitution, any changes made to variables in that subshell disappear when the subshell exits.

Instead, you'll want to set the value of `PS1` *inside* `prompt_fun`, then call `prompt_fun` from the value of `PROMPT_COMMAND`, as the value of that parameter is executed in the current shell context prior to each prompt being displayed.

```
prompt_fun () {
    if [[ -z $CACHE ]]; then
        # Set value of $CACHE
    fi
    PS1=something
    PS1+=something_else
    PS1+=$CACHE
    PS1+=final_value
}

PROMPT_COMMAND='prompt_fun'   # Yes, single quotes
```